# Is this question still "too broad" after edits? Recommendations for further edits?

Tags: discussion

I've edited both the tile and body of the question [Is region-specific blocking built-in to MacOS more extensive than a few emoji?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/328950/143729) with the plan of having it reopened.

I thought there were as many as four (4) reopen votes at one point, there are currently two.

I'd like to know if region-specific blocking functions that Apple includes within MacOS is limited to emojis, or if it is more extensive.

Is this question still too broad? If your answer is "yes", how might it be further edited or formulated to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Hi and thanks for hopping he for a discussion. I haven’t read the edits, but my initial take is you’re asking some5ing that’s more like a wiki article - list all th 5ings that are X.

The big improvement I would say in general - what practical thing are you going to do or prevented from doing? That sort of edit cures almost any ills that cause close votes to accumulate.

Comment: I'll see what I can do, thanks for your reply here and in the comment there as well. I certainly don't want to ask for a list. An answer to "Is... more extensive than a few emoji" could be answered in the affirmative with a *single example*, and in the negative with an answer of the form "As discussed in this article in reputable trade magazine X, the emoji's are a special case, and in general MacOS does not block content." which is  what I'd expected and I"m sort-of surprised such an answer hasn't been forthcoming already!

Comment: If a list were actually *needed* to talk about MacOS content-blocking beyond emoji, that would be both very surprising and quite disconcerting!

Comment: After considering [this comment](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45544275#45544275) about a different question that also had "list-like potential" I realize that that argument might apply here as well.